# How can I read a 3-colums txt file using Java

Tags: java, file, txt

I've tried using the regular methods and I realized that this txt has 3 columns, but one of them has a phrase, so it makes me to have more than 3 columns

[image: the text has spaces between words]

Comment: Can you paste the content showed in picture in your post ? [edit] it and add it. Whas it the separator, multiple spaces or tabs ?

Comment: Read it line by line and then split in 3 parts by the space or tabs and load it somewhere (List, array ..). Maybe this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use method [split(String, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,int)) of class `java.lang.String`.

```java
/*
 * import java.io.File;
 * import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 * import java.util.Arrays;
 * import java.util.Scanner;
 */
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("inputext.txt"))) {
    String line;
    String[] columns;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        line = scanner.nextLine();
        columns = line.split("\\s+", 3);
        if (columns.length == 3) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(columns));
        }
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException x) {
    x.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note that I wrote a text file named *inputext.txt* that contains the sample data from your question.

This is the output I get:

```
[Phone, Account, Message]
[+5215554089954, 123456ABC001, This is a test message]
[5554089954, 123456ABC002, This is a test message]
[53711100, 123456ABC003, This is a test message]
[+525554089954, 123456ABC003, This is a test message]
[015554089954, 123456ABC003, This is a test message]
```